# utilize PHP array as HTML selection

Tags: javascript, php

**What I got.**

I got an PHP which performs a user LDAP query and stores the result in an array. Within the PHP I `JSON_encode($myArray)` the array and pass this to an JavaScript file with `print_r($myArray)`. In JavaScript I fill a HTML selection with the `myArray` as source.

The PHP results looks like, which is fine:

```
["Mickey Mouse","Donald Duck","Minnie Mouse"]
```

**Whats the problem?**

Usually I would fill a source based selection like this, which works with JSON files but not in this case:

```
var fillUserSelection

for (var key in myArray) {
   fillUserSelection += "<option>" + myArray[key] + "</option>"
}
document.getElementbyId("").innerHTML = fillUserSelection
```

I expected `Mickey Mouse`, `Donald Duck` and `Minnie Mouse` as options. Instead I receive each char  as options. Like `[`,`"`,`M`,`i`,`c`,`k`,`e`,`y`.. etc.

**What I want.**

I want only `Mickey Mouse`, `Donald Duck` and `Minnie Mouse` as options. What do I miss?

Comment: Looks like your "array" is still a string. Without seeing your code where you explicitly pass your array to JS from PHP I can't be certain, but you likely need to `JSON.parse` your array, or echo it out from PHP as `var myArray = <?=json_encode($myPHPArray)?>;` Note that I'm not surrounding that json_encode echo with *anything. at all.* If you put quotes around it, it's a string and needs to be parsed.

Comment: @David exactly what I missed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
var myArray = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($phpArray) ?>);
```

Now your array will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php $myarray = array("Mickey Mouse","Donald Duck","Minnie Mouse"); ?>
    
    <?php json_encode($myarray); ?>
    
    
      <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($myarray); $i++) {?>
      
      <?php echo "$myarray[$i] <br/>"; ?>
      
      <?php } ?>
```